# Change-making problem with a twist

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I'm trying to solve the following problem, which is a twist on the change-making problem:

> Given a set $S$ of coins, and a target value $b$, construct an algorithm to find  **all** finite lists of coins satisfying the following properties:
>
> 1. The first $n$ coins in the list are smaller than $k$.
> 2. Each coin *devalues*, that is, the sum of coins is calculated like so:
>      $$
>    C= \sum_{i = m}^{1} max(c_i - (l
>    (m - i)), 0)
>    $$
>      Where $m$ is the length of the list of coins and $l$ is the *loss rate*
> 3. $C = b$, that is, the list sums up to the target value.

To give an example, if the list of coins is $[0.5, 0.25, 0.25]$ and the loss rate $l$ is $0.15$, the sum of that list is $(0.5 - 0.15 * 2) + (0.25 - 0.15 * 1)+ (0.25- 0.15 * 0) = 0.55$.

Lists where some elements make no contribution (there are terms with $c_i - loss = 0$) should not be counted.

I need this algorithm for a real life problem, and after some attempts I couldn't crack it, so for now I'm using basically brute force to find some solutions.

Comment: What should happen if the contribution of a coin is negative? What do you mean by Lists (..) should not be "counted"? Do you mean such lists should not be in the output? How is the list of coins specified? Are there many coins of the same value?

Comment: @LinAlg It can’t, at least it will be 0 (that’s why the ma is there). Yeah, such lists should not be in the output